# Viewpager With tabLayout and PagerTabStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, pagerslidingtabstrip

I Experimented a bit in viewPager.
One viewpager with different FragmentAdapter.
For now the code works perfectly but I don't know if its the right way to do that.

For my Activity is this.

```
public class Navigation extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, TabHost.OnTabChangeListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private ViewPager pager;
public static TabHost tabHost;
public static TabWidget tabWidget;
public static FloatingActionMenu fab;
private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
private String currentTab;
private Button mButton;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
private PagerSlidingTabStrip mTabLayout;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = 0;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    fab = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.fabMenu);
    fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
    tabHost.setup();
    tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(this);
    tabWidget = (TabWidget) findViewById(android.R.id.tabs);
    setNewTab(tabHost, "tab1", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_search, R.id.tab1);
    setNewTab(tabHost, "tab2", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_comment, R.id.tab2);
    setNewTab(tabHost, "tab3", R.string.textTabTitle1, R.drawable.icon_car, R.id.tab3);

    mTabLayout = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.tab);
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapterSearch(getSupportFragmentManager()));
    mTabLayout.setViewPager(pager);
    pager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
    mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectLocation);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mLinearLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    TabIcon.setColor(0, mTabLayout, iconSearchOpac, iconSearch);
}


private void setNewTab(TabHost tabHost, String tag, int title, int icon, int contentID) {
    TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(tag);
    tabSpec.setIndicator(getTabIndicator(tabHost.getContext(), title, icon));
    tabSpec.setContent(contentID);
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
}

private View getTabIndicator(Context context, int title, int icon) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tab_layout, null);
    final ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    iv.setImageResource(icon);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
    tv.setText(title);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (!drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap Again to Exit Toweelo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.navigation, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        } else {
            drawer.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    currentTab = tabId;
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab1")) {
        if (pager != null) {
            pager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapterSearch(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TabIcon.setColor(0, mTabLayout, iconSearchOpac, iconSearch);
        }
    }
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab2")) {
        if (pager != null) {
            pager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapterComments(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            mButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            TabIcon.setColor(0, mTabLayout, iconCommentOpac, iconComment);
        }
    }
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab3")) {
        if (pager != null) {
            pager.setAdapter(new FragmentAdapterCars(getSupportFragmentManager()));
            mButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            TabIcon.setColor(0, mTabLayout, iconCarOpac, iconCar);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab1")) {
        TabIcon.setColor(position, mTabLayout, iconSearchOpac, iconSearch);
    }
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab2")) {
        TabIcon.setColor(position, mTabLayout, iconCommentOpac, iconComment);
    }
    if (currentTab.equalsIgnoreCase("tab3")) {
        TabIcon.setColor(position, mTabLayout, iconCarOpac, iconCar);
    }
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSearch:
            startActivity(new Intent(Navigation.this, SelectCategory.class));
            break;
        case R.id.btnSelectLocation:
            startActivity(new Intent(Navigation.this, SelectLocation.class));

     }
  }
 }
```

And for my XML is this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.toweelo.Navigation">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        >

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent"
                      android:gravity="center_vertical"
                      android:weightSum="10">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btnSelectLocation"
                          android:layout_width="0dp"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:layout_weight="5.5"
                          android:background="@drawable/ripple_effect"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                          android:orientation="horizontal"
                          android:paddingLeft="8dp">
                <com.toweelo.custom.CustomTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:text="Quezon City"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_down_arrow"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="36dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="4.5">
                <Button android:id="@+id/btnSearch"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:background="@drawable/custom_search_button"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_search"
                        android:text="Search"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:textSize="14dp"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
        android:id="@+id/tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsDividerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:pstsIndicatorColor="@color/colorWhite"
        app:pstsIndicatorHeight="3dp"
        app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
        app:pstsTextAllCaps="false"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />
<com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    fab:menu_animationDelayPerItem="50"
    fab:menu_backgroundColor="#B3FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_buttonSpacing="0dp"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="#DA4336"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="#E75043"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#99FFFFFF"
    fab:menu_fab_size="normal"
    fab:menu_icon="@drawable/fab_add"
    fab:menu_labels_colorNormal="@color/colorWhite"
    fab:menu_labels_cornerRadius="3dp"
    fab:menu_labels_ellipsize="none"
    fab:menu_labels_margin="0dp"
    fab:menu_labels_maxLines="-1"
    fab:menu_labels_padding="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingBottom="4dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingLeft="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingRight="8dp"
    fab:menu_labels_paddingTop="4dp"
    fab:menu_labels_position="left"
    fab:menu_labels_showShadow="true"
    fab:menu_labels_singleLine="false"
    fab:menu_labels_textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    fab:menu_labels_textSize="14sp"
    fab:menu_openDirection="up"
    fab:menu_shadowColor="#66000000"
    fab:menu_shadowRadius="4dp"
    fab:menu_shadowXOffset="1dp"
    fab:menu_shadowYOffset="3dp"
    fab:menu_showShadow="true"
    >
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menuIn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_premium"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPremium"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPremiumDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorPremiumAccent"
        fab:fab_label="Premium"
        fab:fab_size="mini"

        />
    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/menuOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_saves"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorSaves"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorSavesDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorSavesAccent"
        fab:fab_label="Saves"
        fab:fab_size="mini"/>

    <com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_edit"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        fab:fab_colorRipple="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_label="Write"
        fab:fab_size="mini"/>
</com.github.clans.fab.FloatingActionMenu>

<TabHost android:id="@+id/tabHost"
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorWhite"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:showDividers="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>

       </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

So I'am wondering if my code will do some errors in the future use?
I mean, will it have out of memory problem since i am using only one viewpager for different adapters.

And for the tab with pagerTabStrip Am i doing it right implemeting it both? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So you are setting a new `FragmentPagerAdapter` on each `TabHost`, thus creating 3 new fragments at runtime when the user clicks another tab. This might cause confusion to the user and if the framgments load heavy resources, greater memory consumption and further user annoyance.

Comment: Each tab has 3 more different fragment with viewpager. Is it really unnecessary?

Comment: Looks like I misread the code. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: maybe.I'm just curious if my code will not produce some Out of memory or something because I am using different fragmentadapter in one viewpager.

Comment: If your fragments are lightweight and you're not using many bitmaps, it is unlikely to have an Out of memory exception. Although dynamic instantiation of fragments might cause some delay, thus creating an unpleasant user experience.

Comment: What would you suggest?.

Comment: My boss wants it that way.. No idea what else to use.

Comment: If he wants it that way, then let it be. It's just that I've not heard anyone using PagerSlidingTab within a TabHost.